# Laravel 5.1 - Organising Factories

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

This seems like it should be a fairly simply question, but with Laravels (5.1) [model factories](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#model-factories), am I supposed to place every model definition inside the one `ModelFactory.php` file?

If, for example, I have 200 different models, I can see this file (`Database\Factories\ModelFactory.php`) getting very large and cluttered.

**My question is:**

Is there a better way to organise model factories, or should I really define them all in that one file? What is best practice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/076a054b6c78888acb3d0b93030402dbf736d824/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factory.php#L43) you can see that it takes the path (/factories) and requires every single file. So you can definitely create as many files as you want in that directory and separate them by concern or model.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I knew it would be something simple! I'll accept when SO lets me :)